# How to find generators for subgroups of free groups?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, free-groups

For simplicity, consider $F_2$ a free group generated by two elements $\{a,b\}$. Let's say I am given a finite index subgroup $H\subset F_2$, for example $H=\{a^{i_1}b^{j_1}...a^{i_n}b^{j_n}:\,i_1+...+i_n=0\,(\mathrm{mod}\, 2)\}=\ker(f:F_2\to\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\,\,\text{by}\,\,a\mapsto1,b\mapsto0\}$. By Nielsen-Schreier theorem, this subgroup is free and is generated by $3$ elements. I figured out that one possible choice can be given by $\{aba^{-1},aba,b\}$, but I could not prove this rigorously.

(1) How to prove that the two subgroups are the same?

(2) While I was thinking about (1), I realized that I could not even show that $\langle aba^{-1},aba,b\rangle$ is normal. So a related question is, given a finite set of generators in $F_2$, is there a general way to determine whether it generates a normal subgroup?

I tried to think about both questions in terms of covering spaces and Cayley graphs, but my knowledge on both subjects are limited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most proofs of the Nielsen-Schreier theorem proceed by following a recipe for finding generators of the subgroup $H$ in $F$ and then proving that they are free generators.

You start by finding a (right) Schreier (= prefix closed) transversal of $H$ in $F$. Let $X$ be a set of free generators of $F$ and, for $g \in F$, let $\bar{g}$ denote the unique element of $U$ with $Hg = H\bar{g}$.

Then the subset of non-identity elements of the set $$\{ux \overline{ux}^{-1} : u \in U, x \in X \}$$
freely generates $H$.

In your example, we can take $U = \{1,a\}$, leading to the free generating set $\{b,a^2,aba^{-1}\}$ of $H$, which is the same as that found in the answer by kabenyuk.

You can check normality of a subgroup $H$ of $F$ by constructing the permutation representation of $F$ on the cosets of $H$ in $F$, and then checking whether the generators of $H$ all act trivially on this set.

The above method of testing for normality is fine for subgroups of moderately small finite index, but for arbitrary finitely generated subgroups, you can use the fact that membership testing in such subgroups is possible (using methods based on Stallings' Folding) and then testing membership of $xgx^{-1}$ and $x^{-1}gx$ in $H$ for all $x \in X$ and generators $g$ of $H$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have a follow up question: why would generators of $H$ acts trivially on cosets space if $H$ is normal? I think you are talking about conjugate action right.

Comment: $H \unlhd G \Leftrightarrow gHg^{-1} = \,\forall g \in G \Leftrightarrow HgH = Hg\, \forall g \in G$. Yes, I'm using right actions, on the right coset space but if you prefer left actions, then it just becomes $H \unlhd G \Leftrightarrow HgH = gH\,\forall g \in G$. And of course, the action of $H$ is trivial if and only if the action of all of its generators are trivial, so it's enough to check the action of the generators of $H$.

Comment: Ah yes. I forgot about that. Thanks again!

Comment: Stallings foldings immediately allow you to test normality, there is no need to test conjugation manually: a (folded) Stallings' graph defines a normal subgroup of $F(X)$ if and only if the graph is "$X$-regular" (for every vertex $v$ and letter $x\in X^{\pm1}$ there exists an edge with initial vertex $v$ and label $x$), and swapping any two vertices induced an automorphism of the graph.

Comment: (This is Theorem 8.14 of Kapovich and Schupp's paper *Stallings' foldings and subgroups of free groups*, J. Algebra, 2000. Also, this paper is a pretty comprehensive introduction to Stallings' folding, incase anyone wants some further reading.)

Answer (score 3):

There is a simpler system of generating groups $H=\langle
aba^{-1},a^2,b\rangle$. How to check it? Since $aba^{-1}\cdot
a^2=aba$, then $H\leq\langle aba^{-1},a^2,b\rangle$. The inverse
inclusion follows from the equality $a^2=(aba^{-1})^{-1}\cdot
aba$.

The answers to your two questions follow from the decidability of
the occurrence problem for free groups. This problem
was solved by J. Nielsen in 1921. I think his algorithms are
stated in books:
Lyndon R.C.,Schupp P.E.,Combinatorial group theory,
Magnus W., Karrass A., Solitar D.,Combinatorial group theory.

---

To answer @Accumulation's question
I will add a few words.
Now we have three subgroups:
$$
\langle aba^{-1},aba,b\rangle,\
\langle aba^{-1},a^2,b\rangle,\ \mathrm{and}\
\operatorname{Ker}(f).
$$
Here $f:F_2\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_2$, $f(a)=1$, $f(b)=0$.
We know that
$$
\langle aba^{-1},aba,b\rangle=\langle aba^{-1},a^2,b\rangle,
$$
$$
\langle aba^{-1},a^2,b\rangle\leq\operatorname{Ker}(f),
$$
$$
|F_2:\operatorname{Ker}(f)|=2.
$$

Let $B=\langle aba^{-1},a^2,b\rangle$.
By induction on the word length of $F_2$ we prove that $F_2=B\cup Ba$.

Let $w\in F_2$.

1. $w=w'a$, $w'\in B$ $\Rightarrow$ $w\in Ba$.
2. $w=w'a$, $w'\in Ba$ $\Rightarrow$ $w'=w''a$, $w''\in B$ $\Rightarrow$ $w=w''\cdot a^2\in B$.
3. $w=w'b$, $w'\in B$ $\Rightarrow$ $w=w'\cdot b\in B$.
4. $w=w'b$, $w'\in Ba$
   $\Rightarrow$ $w'=w''a$, $w''\in B$
   $\Rightarrow$ $w=w''\cdot ab=w''\cdot aba^{-1}\cdot a\in Ba$.

The cases $w=w'a^{-1}$ and $w=w'b^{-1}$ are similarly.

It follows that
$$
|F_2:\langle aba^{-1},a^2,b\rangle|=2.
$$
So $\langle aba^{-1},a^2,b\rangle=\operatorname{Ker}(f)$.

Comment: I don't see how your statement $H=\langle
aba^{-1},a^2,b\rangle$ follows unless you're already assuming $H=\langle
aba^{-1},aba,b\rangle$

Comment: @Acccumulation thank you. I supplemented my post to answer your question.